# Is there a way to create a deb package that installs only on certain distros?

Tags: package-management

We have a certain set of supported OSs. And within that - for debian/ubuntu, we support only wheezy and trusty. Is there anything within the packaging that can control this? That is, the .deb file install will just gracefully fail if not wheezy or trusty. Otherwise, the install should proceed.